# Screen sharing SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, video

Is there any sdk that helps to share the iPad/iPhone app screen to other users via any server or whatever. I am trying to implement such a thing, I could not find anything helpful so thought of taking screen shots of the app and sending to a server and create a video file over there, is it feasible?.

Comment: You might want to estabilish a direct TCP connection to the other device, then use the IOFramebuffer APIs to obtain and send (possibly compressed) data.

Comment: Thanks is there any sample code to do that??

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Look at https://catvision.io - we will release screen sharing SDK for iOS in few days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You require two things: 
i) Screen sharing from iOS 
ii) screen -recording at machine where the iOS device screen is shared.

I am not sure about api but a few apps are available for screen sharing like "[Airserver](http://www.airserver.com/) "

and "[Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/)" I personally find airserver better than reflector.

Answer (score 2):

I could easily see Apple rejecting that app if you plan on implementing that feature in the released version. However [Soasta Touch Test](http://www.soasta.com/products/touchtest/) may be a good debugging and testing solution. Soasta has a pretty sophisticated set of tools for debugging in the cloud.